# Is there a Facebook API to publish content to the FaceBook page using PHP?

Tags: php, facebook

I have a travel site and whenever I publish a new offer, I want to automatically update our sites FaceBook page.

Is there an API I can use for this?
Are there any recommended tutorials showing how to do this?

Our content is published with PHP.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Any other questions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are many ways for doing the same.

The most common one is to create a Facebook App for your Website.
**https://developers.facebook.com/apps**

Download the Facebook Development Kit from this URL based on the language you are using for development.
**https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdks/**

This SDK will have the required Classes and functions call to help you submit contents from your web-page to your Facebook Page.

Go Ahead and have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example

```
$data = array(
        "link" => $link,
        "access_token" => $pages,
        "picture" => $image,
        "name"=> $title,
        "description"=> $description
);


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://graph.facebook.com/".$pageID."/feed");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$op = curl_exec($ch);
 if (!$op) {
  echo "Curl Error : ".curl_error($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  exit;
}

curl_close($ch);
$res = get_object_vars(json_decode((string)$op));
print_r($res);
```